# How to avoid delay in UpdateAttribute

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

A flow consumes files from Kafka, assigns S3 partition based on the `kafka.timestamp` attribute from the ConsumeKafka processor, merges them, and puts the resulting files into respective S3 subfolders.
S3 partition is assigned via the UpdateAttribute processor that uses the following formula to create the partition
`${kafka.timestamp:format("yyyy:MM:dd")}`. During the last 1-5 seconds of the day, the partition is being assigned the wrong way and the files containing records from day 1 are being put into partition of the day 2. What could be the reason and how can this be prevented?

Comment: UpdateAttribute is very fast, is it the Merge processor that causes the delay? What is your configuration for UpdateAttribute and the Merge processor? I recommend setting `Run Schedule` to `0 sec` and `Run Duration` to `25 ms` for UpdateAttribute, and if all the merged files will have the same attribute, maybe you can have the UpdateAttribute before the Merge?

Comment: The update is already before merge. I even tried to remove the merge step - it didn't help. Config for UpdateAttribute is the following: Scheduling Strategy 
**Timer driven**
Concurrent Tasks 
**5**
Run Schedule 
**0 sec**
Execution 
**All nodes**
Run Duration 
**00:00:00.000**

Comment: Try Run Duration at 25 msec

Comment: This didn't help either.

Comment: You can check the provenance for the FlowFiles where the partition is being set incorrectly, perhaps it is being held too long upstream and by the time it gets to UpdateAttribute it's "too late"

Comment: It might be more helpful besides looking at provenance events individually to generate a lineage graph from the provenance dialog for the FlowFile(s), then you can track the FlowFile from when it was created until it gets to UpdateAttribute in the flow.